# connection returns none (pymssql)

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

I am trying to connect to the a sql server with pymssql package.

```
from os import getenv 
import pymssql 

server = '....'
user='username'
password='password'
conn= pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "database")

print conn
```

(I have python object in memory when I print 'conn' )

now if I do

```
cursor.execute("SELECT @@VERSION")
conn.close()
```

I receive None, when I try to get "SELECT @@VERSION" and/or trying to query a table from python script.

Comment: See the duplicate question for your answer.

Comment: yeah, should have read that. but yes, thanks guys. VERY HELPFUL.